# How to create a shell script from an existing script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, echo

Hello I was wondering how it would be possible to create a shell script from an existing  shell script? I am currently having already a script done which should be created, it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

uptime=$(</proc/uptime)
uptime=${uptime%%.*}
user=$(whoami)
seconds=$(( uptime%60 ))
minutes=$(( uptime/60%60 ))
hours=$(( uptime/60/60%24 ))
days=$(( uptime/60/60/24 ))
echo -e "
\033[0;35m+++++++++++++++++++: \033[0;37mServer Data\033[0;35m :+++++++++++++++++++
\033[0;35m+  \033[0;37mHostname \033[0;35m= \033[1;32m`hostname`
\033[0;35m+    \033[0;37mKernel \033[0;35m= \033[1;32m`uname -r`
\033[0;35m+      \033[0;37mTime \033[0;35m= \033[1;32m`date +%k:%M:%S`
\033[0;35m+    \033[0;37mUptime \033[0;35m= \033[1;32m$days d ~ $hours h ~ $minutes m ~ $seconds s
\033[0;35m+       \033[0;37mCPU \033[0;35m= \033[1;32m`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | cut -c 14-100 | uniq`
\033[0;35m+    \033[0;37mMemory \033[0;35m= \033[1;32m`cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | awk {'print $2'}` kB
\033[0;35m++++++++++++++++++++: \033[0;37mUser Data\033[0;35m :++++++++++++++++++++
\033[0;37m+  \033[0;37mUsername \033[0;35m= \033[1;32m$user
\033[0;35m+  \033[0;37mSessions \033[0;35m= \033[1;32m`who | grep $user | wc -l` of 14
\033[0;35m+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\e[m 
"
```

The only problem I see, is that commands like 'cat' or 'grep' would get them echo'ed out interpreted, instead of being just printed out. So that's why I am asking here how something like this could be one.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this using *here-doc* and the special trick with the single quotes around (no interpolation) :

```
cat<<'EOF'>script.sh
#!/bin/bash

uptime=$(</proc/uptime)
uptime=${uptime%%.*}
user=$(whoami)
seconds=$(( uptime%60 ))
minutes=$(( uptime/60%60 ))
hours=$(( uptime/60/60%24 ))
days=$(( uptime/60/60/24 ))
echo -e "
\033[0;35m+++++++++++++++++++: \033[0;37mServer Data\033[0;35m :+++++++++++++++++++
\033[0;35m+   \033[0;37mAddress \033[0;35m= \033[1;32m109.163.233.49
\033[0;35m+  \033[0;37mHostname \033[0;35m= \033[1;32m`hostname`
\033[0;35m+    \033[0;37mKernel \033[0;35m= \033[1;32m`uname -r`
\033[0;35m+      \033[0;37mTime \033[0;35m= \033[1;32m`date +%k:%M:%S`
\033[0;35m+    \033[0;37mUptime \033[0;35m= \033[1;32m$days d ~ $hours h ~ $minutes m ~ $seconds s
\033[0;35m+       \033[0;37mCPU \033[0;35m= \033[1;32m`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | cut -c 14-100 | uniq`
\033[0;35m+    \033[0;37mMemory \033[0;35m= \033[1;32m`cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | awk {'print $2'}` kB
\033[0;35m++++++++++++++++++++: \033[0;37mUser Data\033[0;35m :++++++++++++++++++++
\033[0;37m+  \033[0;37mUsername \033[0;35m= \033[1;32m$user
\033[0;35m+  \033[0;37mSessions \033[0;35m= \033[1;32m`who | grep $user | wc -l` of 14
\033[0;35m+     \033[0;37mAdmin \033[0;35m= \033[1;32mSergey Ruslan
\033[0;35m+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\e[m 
"
EOF
```